# Saving ".txt" to specific directory using Windows XP and 7

Tags: c++, stl, c++builder, ofstream, c++builder-6

I'm trying to save a text file to specific directory using `ofstream` (C++ Builder). I'm having problems with Windows 7.

```c
// Works fine at Windows XP and Windows 7
std::ofstream file1("Name.txt"); 

// Works fine at Windows XP but not at Windows 7
std::ofstream file1("Folder1/Name.txt"); 

// Works fine at Windows XP but not at Windows 7
std::ofstream file1("Folder1\\Name.txt");
```

How can I save a ".txt" file to specific directory using Windows 7?

OBS: When I save the program using Windows 7, the file is saved in:

C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Folder1\Name.txt

Comment: Have you tried running the app "As Administrator", maybe it is an issue with permissions.

Comment: @shenles: Running the app as Administrator is the absolutely **wrong** suggestion. It violates every updated security restriction and improvement made since Windows Vista was released, and is simply poor programming practice unless you have specific reasons for doing so. It's the equivalent of running all processes as `root` on a *nix system.

Comment: I completely agree, but it will quickly diagnose the issue is with permissions, and not with how the code tries to create the file

Answer (score 4):

First, stop using relative paths, as they are relative to the calling process's current working directory, which changes dynamically during a process's lifetime.  Always use absolute paths instead.  Use backslashes instead of forward slashes, and make sure to escape backslashes only in string literals, eg:

```
std::ofstream file1("C:\\Folder1\\Name.txt");
```

Second, make sure the user account that is running your app has security rights to access the folder and write the file.  Vista and later are much more restrictive than XP, especially if UAC is enabled.  Many folders are read-only, especially if your app is installed under the "Program Files" folder.  Never write to your program's installation folder or a subfolder of it.  Use the special folders that Windows sets asside for user-related and app-related files.

Comment: I wouldn't say to always use absolute paths. Often the user can unzip/install your app into any directory, so you use relative paths to find you files relative to the working directory of the exe.

Comment: ? You say to always use forward slashes, and then to illustrate your point, you give an example where you use backslashes instead?

Comment: @JoeWhite: I got the terminology reversed, but you know what I meant.  Use "\" ("\\" in literals) instead of "/" as the path separator.

Comment: @KenWhite: I wouldn't mess with the CWD unless absolutely necessary.  Using the install folder as the base of an absolute path is better.

Comment: @Remy, I didn't intend that anyone "mess with it", but you're right - my wording is wrong (not even "unclear", but wrong), because it's misleading. Thanks. Deleting the comment.